# coding for the logger in Java project

Tags: java

HI Can you tell me please where do I put the logger code in the constructor file?

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  


        // This block configures the logger with handler and formatter  
      FileHandler  fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
```

Project is failing in the read here:

```
_internal_parameter_table.clear();
            _internal_parameter_table.put("OPOPTT", 2);
            _internal_parameter_table.put("OPOPID", templateName);
            srbopt.read(_internal_parameter_table, 1);
            defaultNameSrbnax01 = defaultNameSrbnax01.set(srbopt
                    .getBy("OPDF01"));
            defaultNameSrbnox02 = defaultNameSrbnox02.set(srbopt
                    .getBy("OPDF02"));
            defaultNameSrbcmx06 = defaultNameSrbcmx06.set(srbopt
                    .getBy("OPDF06"));
            defaultNameSrbtpdx15 = defaultNameSrbtpdx15.set(srbopt
                    .getBy("OPDF15"));
            defaultNameSrbnax01 = defaultNameSrbnax01.set(defaultNameSrbnax01
                    .trimBlanks(true, true, false, false, false));
            defaultNameSrbnox02 = defaultNameSrbnox02.set(defaultNameSrbnox02
                    .trimBlanks(true, true, false, false, false));
            defaultNameSrbcmx06 = defaultNameSrbcmx06.set(defaultNameSrbcmx06
                    .trimBlanks(true, true, false, false, false));
            defaultNameSrbtpdx15 = defaultNameSrbtpdx15
                    .set(defaultNameSrbtpdx15.trimBlanks(true, true, false,
                            false, false));
```

Comment: Why do you need the logger to be assigned to the class instance? Should it has a static scope so each object of that class can access it?

Comment: we have issue with project failing on data it seems. I want to see the values of the data

Comment: Try to use it as a static member so you can access it from other classes too

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample. It works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
FileHandler fh;  

try {  

    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
    fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

    // the following statement is used to log any messages  
    logger.info("My first log");  

} catch (SecurityException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
logger.info("Hi How r u?");
```

}

Produces the output at MyLogFile.log

Jan 2, 2016 9:57:08 AM testing.MyLogger main
INFO: My first log
Jan 2, 2016 9:57:08 AM testing.MyLogger main
INFO: Hi How r u?

To remove the console handler, use

logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

since the ConsoleHandler is registered with the parent logger from which all the loggers derive.

Comment: HI Naveen, thanks looks good but am getting error 'logger cannot be resolved to a type'

Comment: Hey Bipin, I have used java.util.logging here, can you confirm in your code whether you have imported this?